# Will my Blue Java Banana plant recover after splitting in two?

Tags: banana

Will my Blue Java Banana plant recover after getting top heavy and splitting in two?  It's right above soil level.

I got it last spring, it's got some healthy roots but no sign of it doing anything. It's indoors because I live in Arkansas but when spring comes it will be put back into the soil outside. What should I be doing with it or looking out for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A picture would help, perhaps! Also, If you see suckers growing by the foot of the tree (technically it's a herb), the suckers can be propagated or left as it is to grow into mature tree. What is the age of the tree? If its older than a year(approximately), and it's growing in a large container, then it should probably have a well established corm. The corm will produce suckers till it produces new child corms and old one dies off.

If the core of your plant (from where fresh new leaves sprout) is itself healthy and unaffected, you shouldn't worry much about anything. Also, a banana herb dies off after going to fruit, and produces baby suckers near roots which continue cycle. So, if occurence of frost is ruled out (considering it's indoors), you don't have to worry much.

Comment: I tried to add the picture and just a normal picture off my phone and it's saying it's to large to upload. this is my first post on this website please bare with me .

Comment: @MonicaTeconchuk Try compressing it from any websites on the web for and so on and then try to re-upload the same, if you will. Here's one such site: https://imageresizer.com/image-compressor